# How can I upload a video with eager transcriptions applied?

Tags: url, request, cloudinary

How can I upload a video to cloudinary with transcriptions applied on upload rather than request?

I'm passing the `raw_convert=google_speech` parameter to generate my transcriptions file in the upload request.
Since the transcriptions are generated in the upload request and the transcription file is typically specified by the `eager=l_myTranscription.transcript` param, I don't know how form my request.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply google speech on upload. Example in JAVA:

cloudinary.uploader().upload("", ObjectUtils.asMap("resource_type", "video", "raw_convert","google_speech:srt:vtt"));

A transcript file with the same name will be generated and you can use that as an overlay to your video. More information: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/google_ai_video_transcription_addon

Comment: Right, but when dealing with large files the transcript must be provided at the time of upload so it can be processed prior to the GET request. I've tried to pass `eager=l_subtitles:anticipatedTranscript.transcript` at upload time but this does not work.